# How do I fix this "line_search_wolfe2" error when using sci-kit learn?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I am getting an error when trying to run a Python script that implements Sci-Kit Learn. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()
print (digits.data)
print (digits.target)
print (digits.images[0])

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

x, y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1]
```

And here is the error I get when running "python scidigits.py"
in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Practice.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn import svm
  File "/home/jdoe/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC, \
  File "/home/jdoe/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 6, in <module>
from ..linear_model.base import LinearClassifierMixin, SparseCoefMixin, \
  File "/home/jdoe/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from .logistic import (LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV,
  File "/home/jdoe/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 25, in <module>
from ..utils.optimize import newton_cg
  File "/home/jdoe/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/optimize.py", line 18, in <module>
from scipy.optimize.linesearch import line_search_wolfe2, line_search_wolfe1
ImportError: cannot import name line_search_wolfe2
```

Could anybody please shed light on this issue?

Comment: This is not a "compiler error", it is an `ImportError`. It cannot import the name `line_search_wolfe2`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a version / deprecation problem.

So you should update your scikit-learn package.

Comment: i tried updating both sci-kit learn and scipy i used   `pip install --user --install-option="--prefix= -U scikit-learn` and `easy_install scipy`

Comment: Is not possible that remained some parts of the earlier scikit version? If yes you should wipe all traces of them, if not or it will even not work, you should ask it the sckit forum or group or whatever.

Comment: could using python 2.6.6 be the problem?

Comment: Hard to tell, but I can say that for me in Python 2.76 works well.

Comment: I am now installing Python 3.4.3 and doing package stuff so I guess Ill try it after this